# Use of tense in a sentence

Tags: grammar

The below is the excerpt from an [online article](https://www.lifehack.org/articles/productivity/10-reasons-why-some-people-feel-like-they-dont-have-enough-time.html). Could anyone explain why the present perfect tense is used in the bold fonted part?

*Do not start and plug through every task until **you’ve asked** this question: “Do I really need to do this now?”*

Comment: If you do as the instruction says, when you start a task you will already _have asked_ yourself the question (and answered 'Yes').

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying explanation!